# drools on wildfly is not working

Tags: wildfly, drools

I am new to drools.
I am using drools 6.5.0 and wildfly 10.

I am developing a REST application with drools rules and executing through REST url.

My drools rules are executed in eclipse perfectly.  After that I have deployed my REST application on wildfly.  It is successful.

But, If I call the url from browser, it throws the below exception in console.

Is it mandatory to deploy KIE server for the rule execution?  Because in tomcat the same application is working fine without KIE server.

droolsTest.java

```
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();  //This statement is working fine
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer(); // Error is thrown in this statement    
            KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

            Message message = new Message();
            message.setMessage("Hello World Testing");
            message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
            kSession.insert(message);
            kSession.fireAllRules();
            System.out.println("Drools Rules execution is Completed");



14:47:43,604 INFO  [stdout] (default task-19) Error caught :java.lang.NoClassDef
FoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieC
ontainerImpl
14:47:43,607 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Co
uld not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl
14:47:43,625 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.drools.compiler.kie.build
er.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:135)
14:47:43,626 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.drools.compiler.kie.build
er.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:101)
14:47:43,626 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.drools.compiler.kie.build
er.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:79)
14:47:43,627 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at com.sample.DroolsTest.drools(
DroolsTest.java:45)
14:47:43,627 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at com.abc.rest.MessageRestSe
rvice.TestDroolsCode(MessageRestService.java:29)
14:47:43,628 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:47:43,628 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:47:43,628 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodA
ccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:47:43,629 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invo
ke(Method.java:498)
14:47:43,630 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.Resou
rceLocatorInvoker.createResource(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:79)
14:47:43,630 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.Resou
rceLocatorInvoker.createResource(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:58)
14:47:43,631 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.Resou
rceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)
14:47:43,631 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.Synch
ronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
14:47:43,632 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.Synch
ronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
14:47:43,634 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.se
rver.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:
221)
14:47:43,635 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.se
rver.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
14:47:43,638 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.se
rver.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
14:47:43,639 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServle
t.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
14:47:43,640 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
14:47:43,641 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.jav
a:62)
14:47:43,641 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
14:47:43,642 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.wildfly.extension.underto
w.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssoci
ationHandler.java:78)
14:47:43,644 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.P
redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
14:47:43,645 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociatio
nHandler.java:131)
14:47:43,647 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCal
lHandler.java:57)
14:47:43,649 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.P
redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
14:47:43,653 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.security.handlers
.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.jav
a:46)
14:47:43,655 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidenti
alityConstraintHandler.java:64)
14:47:43,657 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.security.handlers
.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.j
ava:60)
14:47:43,658 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSess
ionHandler.java:77)
14:47:43,661 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.security.handlers
.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
14:47:43,663 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.security.handlers
.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContext
AssociationHandler.java:43)
14:47:43,664 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.P
redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
14:47:43,665 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at org.wildfly.extension.underto
w.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

14:47:43,665 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.P
redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
14:47:43,668 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.P
redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
14:47:43,669 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
14:47:43,670 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
14:47:43,671 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
14:47:43,672 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
14:47:43,675 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.Serv
letRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction
.java:48)
14:47:43,676 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.Cont
extClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
14:47:43,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.Legac
yThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
14:47:43,681 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.Legac
yThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
14:47:43,682 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.Legac
yThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
14:47:43,686 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.Legac
yThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
14:47:43,695 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.Legac
yThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
14:47:43,702 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
14:47:43,703 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
14:47:43,704 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
14:47:43,704 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors
.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
14:47:43,705 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServer
Exchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
14:47:43,705 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPo
olExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
14:47:43,706 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPo
olExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
14:47:43,706 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.j
ava:745)
14:47:43,707 INFO  [stdout] (default task-19) Executed
```

Could anyone provide your help.

Thanks

Senthil

Comment: There is no requirement to deploy Kie Server for the rule execution, Drools can be used embedded in your application - as your use-case seems to suggest is the actual scenario; the Kie Server is another alternative way to deploy and architect rule/process/etc. KJAR execution.

Based on the partial stacktrace provided, it seems the Drools runtime dependencies are not correctly deployed on your Wildfly installation.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I have included the following line in standalone.xml                                                                       
       <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <global-modules>
                <module name="drools" slot="main"/>
            </global-modules>                                                                                            and my drools folder is having all the libraries which was downloaded from drools site "drools-distribution-6.5.0.Final"

Comment: and module.xml is <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="drools"><resources>
  <resource-root path="drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
  <resource-root path="drools-core-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>resource-root path="drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
  <resource-root path="drools-jsr94-6.5.0.Final.jar"/><resource-root path="drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar"/><resource-root path="drools-templates-6.5.0.Final.jar"/><resource-root path="kie-api-6.5.0.Final.jar"/><resource-root path="kie-internal-6.5.0.Final.jar"/><resource-root path="mvel2-2.2.8.Final.jar"/></resources></module>

Comment: but still it is not working.  My doubt is if the drools runtime is not loading properly then how this line is working "KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();".  Can you provide any link in which how to include drools runtime in wildfly

Comment: If I add all the drools libraries in WEB-INF/lib folder then the rules are executed fine.  So, The global modules configured in wildfly is not correctly loaded, it seems.  Is there any reference to add global module in wildfly